# Create a hyperlink that opens multiple images in one page using html

Tags: html

How can I create a clickable link that opens multiple images in one page only? I host all my images in photobucket. I was able to create a link to open one image only but not multiple images simultaneously.

Comment: Please post your code...

Comment: He is confused with his own question and don't know what to do. But what he wants can be simply achieved by jQuery show/hide functions.

Answer (score 0):

put your images inside a sperated html file like "images.html"
and link the hyperlink to that page

```
<a href="images.html">click me </a>
```

this is HTML sample page:  put all images in images folder in the same HTML page root directory

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<img src="/images/01.jpg"/> <br>
<img src="/images/01.jpg"/> <br>
<img src="/images/01.jpg"/> <br>
<img src="/images/01.jpg"/> <br>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: can you please tell me how can I put all images in separated html file? thank you

Comment: in the link <img src="/images/01.jpg"/> <br>
does "/images/01.jpg"/ is an example of an image link as this <img src=http://i1097.photobucket.com/albums/g342/REVENUEEEE/Untitled.jpg> I use hosting site to creat links for images (photo bucket) you said put all images in images forlder in the same html page root directory? sorry i did not not understand that please explan that to me

Comment: replace "/images/01.jpg"   with some thing like "http:// www.siet.com/image.jpg"
without space between http// and www

Comment: I reached this now what to do                                  <html>
<head></head>
<body>
<img src=http://i1097.photobucket.com/albums/g342/REVENUEEEE/Untitled-1.jpg>
<img src=http://i1097.photobucket.com/albums/g342/REVENUEEEE/Untitled-2.jpg>
<img src=http://i1097.photobucket.com/albums/g342/REVENUEEEE/Untitled-3.jpg>
</body>

</html>

Comment: put it in separated html file MAN

Comment: sorry but i dont know how to make or put it in a separated html file would you please tell me how to do that to rach this link        <a href="images.html">click me </a> thank you for your patience

Comment: just create a new file using note pad or whatever, to and past the code; then save the file with name page.html and make sure your choosing all files from file type , check the picture in my answer

Comment: I think I am almost there. after doing what you told me I got an internet Icon on desktop when double click it opend the 3 pic. in one page. link of this page is C:\Users\layth\Desktop\page.html now how can i use this in a website I want to add it to a wbsite and make it clickable to open these images??

Comment: I sell stamps on ebay website and i need to use a link that when click it it open all images in one page

Answer (score 0):

Keep all 6 files in same directory
Image1(Name:html1.html)

```
<html><body>
 <img src="/image1.jpg"><br>
 </body></html>
```

Image2(Name:html2.html)

```
<html><body>
 <img src="/image2.jpg"><br>
 </body></html>
```

Image3(Name:html3.html)

```
<html><body>
 <img src="/image3.jpg"><br>
 </body></html>
```

Image4(Name:html4.html)

```
<html><body>
 <img src="/image4.jpg"><br>
 </body></html>
```

Image5(Name:html5.html)

```
<html><body>
 <img src="image5.jpg"><br>
 </body></html>
```

Main html

```
<html><body>
<a href="html1.html">image1</a>
 <a href="html2.html">image2</a>
 <a href="html3.html">image3</a>
 <a href="html4.html">image4</a>
 <a href="html5.html">image5</a>
 </body></html>
```

I am a newbie and just a 12-year old boy.
Apologies for any mistakes

Comment: hey, we're same, i'm 12 years old too :D

Comment: thank you I think I am almost there. after doing what you told me I got an internet Icon on desktop when double click it opend the 3 pic. in one page. link of this page is C:\Users\layth\Desktop\page.html now how can i use this in a website I want to add it to a wbsite and make it clickable to open these images?? I sell stamps on ebay website and i need to use a link that when click it it open all images in one page

Comment: @LAYTHZAKAR I am not very sure what you really want to achieve, please check my answer and then tell if it's what you are looking for 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14180428/1391805

Comment: I need to creat listing with clickable links that open a page with nultiple pictures as in this ebay listing. please follow this linck here http://www.ebay.com/itm/Columbia-Much-Mint-Collection-in-Older-Album-/150975062613?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2326d0a255

Comment: @LAYTHZAKAR , Use web hosting sites to host all the 6 files in internet.Instead of "image1.jpg", "image2.jpg" etc, use the url of image provided by the webhost. And same way instead of"html1.html", "html2.html", etc. Use Url of file provided by webhost.

Answer (score 0):

Working Example : http://jsbin.com/eluqod/4/

You don't need to be an expert. If you have the basic knowledge of HTML and JavaScript you can do it on your own. The easiest option is to use [jQuery framework](http://jquery.com), it's a less write, do more JavaScript library that makes interactive web design easy.

What you have to do is create a `<div>` container and put all your images using HTML's `<img>` now you have to include the jQuery library in your document

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Now use the `hide` and `show` or any other effects like FadeToggle, SlideToggle etc. effects (http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) to toggle hide and show for the image container div. Setup your complete page with the image container and the link, first hide the image container using `display:none;` and now use the jQuery function to trigger a function on click of that anchor element.

This is the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#showimg').on('click',function(){

   //Trigger FadeToggle function on click
   $('.image-container').fadeToggle();  

  });
});
```

And the HTML

```
    <a id='showimg'>Hide/Show Images</a>

   <div class='image-container' style='display:none;'>
      <img src='images/sample.png'/>
        <img src='images/sample.png'/>
        <img src='images/sample.png'/>
        <img src='images/sample.png'/>
        <img src='images/sample.png'/>
    </div>
```

Do remember to add the JavaScript library in your page.

check the code to learn about it: http://jsbin.com/eluqod/4/edit

Comment: from what you describe it tells me that I have no knowledge in HTML just very little. I sell stamps on ebay and have many pictures for each lost I host those images in photo bucket. what I need to do is creat a clickable link that when I click on it it open a page contain all images I don't want this link to direct to photobucket websit but only to pictures

Comment: Then why don't you use `<img src='YOUR-PHOBUCKET-IMAGE-URL'/>` to display those images directly on the page (without loading the image files separately) ?

Comment: this link can not contain an effect the link should be cleare as (click here to view first 100 Pictures) when a guest clik on it it open a page with chosen 100 pictures I set for this link. now I was able to create and html page with the link C:\Users\layth\Desktop\page.html it contain the images I want to list but but I dont know where to go from here and how to use it in ebay website??

Comment: answer your last replay. This is what I used to do but I have a listing contain 896 image if I do this for all the internet dos not open all of them thats why I want to separate each 100 picture in one link total of 9 links so when a guest click on it it open a page with 100 pic chosen

Comment: this way it will upload faster and it will be organized this is a sample item selling on ebay please check it out I dont know how they do it and I want mine to be the same please copy and past this link in browser http://www.ebay.com/itm/Columbia-Much-Mint-Collection-in-Older-Album-/150975062613?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2326d0a255

Comment: ^ Ohh, it's better to see an example of what you are trying to do. I will check it and reply you with the answer.

Comment: i will be so greatfull if you helped me getting through this thank you in advance please remember that all waht I have is images hosted in photo bucket hope you explane this issue in 1 2 3 steps. thanks

Comment: @LAYTHZAKAR I have posted a new answer, please check it. Also remember you need a server to host your HTML files and if possible also read about HTML and basic web development online.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create different HTML files for all your image sets. You don't only have create the HTML files, you also have to upload those HTML documents online on a server so people can access it from anywhere.

**1. Create an HTML file**
Open notepad or any plain text editor and paste this in your file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Your page title</title>
  <style type='text/css'>
    .image-container {text-align:center;}
    img {width:80%;height:auto;display:block;margin:10px auto;border:2px solid black;padding:5px;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2> The first 50 pictures (or whatever title you want)</h2>

<!-- Images below -->

<div class='image-container'>

  <!-- Each images are in img tag, put the photobucket images link into the src attribute. Repeat the img tags if you want more images -->

  <img src='http://i923.photobucket.com/albums/ad77/kihani_1996/Troll_Face_.png'/>

  <img src='http://i923.photobucket.com/albums/ad77/kihani_1996/Troll_Face_.png'/>

  <img src='http://i923.photobucket.com/albums/ad77/kihani_1996/Troll_Face_.png'/>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And save it with an understandable name ending with .html `[name].html` and save type as All Files - Make sure to save the file with encoding UTF-8. Just make the necessary changes and upload it to a server and link it.

Repeat the steps for more other HTML files with different images in it.

Comment: thank you. I did all that and it gave me a page with the images. now the link of this page is  C:\Users\layth\Desktop\Images.html who can I upload it to a server or ebay and link it?? when you say server do you mean a site like Photobucket or ebay directly?? or it is somthing eals

Comment: the Images I added are already in photobucket that leave me with the obtion of ebay server. please not after I link this page to a server i need it to put it in a clickable link

Comment: Oh, the main problem is that you don't have a web-host to upload your HTML files online. First see what's a web host is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_hosting_service

There are lots of web host services online, like godaddy, hostgator etc. There are both free and paid web host service, but to make sure your file doesn't get deleted without your knowledge I suggest you to go with a paid web-host service. And then upload the HTML files to the server.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use free data storage services like dropbox to host your HTML files for free of cost. 
http://lifehacker.com/5528104/use-dropbox-to-share-and-host-your-web-site

Comment: hello again. thank you very much for the information. and the great help. I subscribed today in Justhost.com and got my own domain. I got an FTP clint and created forlder and uploaded some images to it now the images are on a server. if you follow this link you will be able to see the the link of each image www.bossf22.com/layth/redbox1 what I could not do is generat links for all images at once in in any way and i need to generate them in an <img src=> in order use them creating the page with images I need using the HTML description codeing you gave me. can you please where to go from here??

Comment: Ohh great ! Now create an HTML page and put the your images link into the src attribute. When you create the web page (HTML file) upload it to your host, just like you uploaded your images and then you will get the link to your page. Just try uploading one page and then do the rest with different images in other pages, also give the HTML pages a different title so you can identify them. If you aren't sure what to do about the `img` tags, this document will help you
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/img

Comment: I UPLOADED THE HTML PAGE FROM MY DESKTOP TO THE SERVER AND IT WORKED PERFECTLY http://www.bossf22.com/layth/PAGE_HTML/page.html BUT THE ISSUE I AM FACEING IS DIFFERENT NOW, I CAN NOT GENERAT LINKS FOR ALL IMAGES AT ONCE AS I USE TO DO WITH PHOTO BUCKET. EACH IMAGE HAS A URL BUT I DONT KNOW HOW TO GET ALL ERLS IN ONE STEP EVEN A URL IS NOT ENOUGH IT NEEDS TO BE IN A FORMAT OF <IMG SRC=> AS IT IS NOT POSSIBLE TO ADD THE CODEING <IMG SRC=> FOR EACH IMAGE FOR HUNDREDS OF IMAGES BUY TYPING IT ONE BY ONE.i DID NOT UNDERSTAND MUCH OF THE LAST LINK YOU GAVE TO ME.

Comment: You may continue hosting your images on Photobucket if it's easier for you. 

And for the `<img>` tag, you don't have to write it all, you can simply copy and paste the previous img tag to the next line and just change the URL in `src` atrribute.

Comment: it sounds good idea. but I dont know which tag to copy and past that you mentioned. can you please show me how to do it with these 3 links

Comment: http://i1097.photobucket.com/albums/g342/REVENUEEEE/Untitled-1.jpg
http://i1097.photobucket.com/albums/g342/REVENUEEEE/Untitled-2.jpg
http://i1097.photobucket.com/albums/g342/REVENUEEEE/Untitled-3.jpg

Comment: an http:\\ comes befor each link

Comment: just to let you know you changed my career I wish you win a million $$$

Comment: I  understand what you said by the copy and past but can I do that by just adding a code that will directly generate <img src=> for each link??

Comment: wow. I did it I found the solution in photo bucket. thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu vey much god bless you

Comment: Yup, in Photobucket you have the option for it's HTML code on the right pane, copying and pasting it on the HTML page will work. And I think you found that :D 

Great !

Comment: in poto bucket they have the option to generate link coads that I did not know how to do with my pictures in just host .com. in photo bucket when you open album you can chose show all pictures then scrol down to the end of page then sellect all imagesthen choose an action click on generate link codes it open a link coade generat page with links of all the urls just on click on the needed links it copy then past in the html you gave me it is long process i guess there is shorter one without using photo bucket hope to learn it one day